# How do I do a theme (css) switch in a chm and make it stay?

Tags: javascript, css, cookies, themes, chm

### About me

My first post! I'm a tech writer who occasionally dabbles in scripting javascript/jQuery etc to accomplish things in our help file (chm file). But I use it infrequently, and know enough to do be dangerous. I consider myself a beginner (maybe advanced beginner) in js scripting.

### What I'm trying to do

I have a chm file (compiled Html Help file) that resides on users' local systems. My end goal is to allow users to click on links within the chm to do some dynamic theme swapping and load in a different .css file for light/dark/classic themes. 
(This discussion I started on Adobe forums shows what I'm attempting:
https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2196246)

### Conditions and Tools

- Our users often won't have access to the Internet.
- The Chms are local
  on their machine, so any solution needs to be done with that in mind.
- Note that
  chm files use IE 7 under the hood.
- Our authoring tool is RoboHelp
  2015.

### The issue

The chm does properly load different css style sheets when I click a link in a topic.

But the issue is, **how do I track a user's choice from a chm file?** Is this even possible?

### Things I've tried

First, I tried cookies. But from my research online and my own personal tests, cookies do not work in a chm. I've confirmed that they do work in a local .htm however. The trick is how do I get the value back into the chm?

Second, I tried iframes. Since the local .htm was able to set cookies, I created a local .htm in the same folder as the .chm. I then used tried to get the chm to pull in that .htm

Here's more or less what I did:

```
var cookiefile = "cookietest.html";
var iframesrc = '<iframe src="' + cookiefile + '" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" name="myFrame" id="myFrame"></iframe>';
$("div#headercolored").append(iframesrc);
```

But the chm topic always shows that iframe portion as "Page not displayed."

Third, I tried to use scripting to locate the external file and send info that way. (I used this as a guide: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644690.aspx)

I can link to the .htm file. I can show it in the chm. I can even send parameters to it. But I cannot get parameters back from it into the chm. For example, in this test snippet, I'm merely trying to see if I can get a single parameter (the value of handled) back from the local .htm page to the calling chm topic. (Eventually, I'll modify it to pass the css value back too.)

```
if (theme == 'default') {
    location.href = prevURL + '?handled=true';
    //prevURL is the chm link and looks something like this:
    //mk:@MSITStore:D:\hg\LocalTest\introtest\!SSL!\Microsoft_HTML_Help\introtest.chm::/3D_Grid.htm  
}
```

The intent of the above code is also so I don't get caught in an infinite loop. The chm topic will supposedly check for "handled=true" and if it sees it and then it won't call the function in the external .htm that queries the cookie status.

But it doesn't work. location.href = prevURL by itself does reopen the calling topic but if I include the "?handled=true" portion, it says "This page can't be displayed".

### Conclusion

Am I even going about the quest for storing and getting cookies the right way? Or is there a better way to do this given the above conditions?

Comment: Is this application help where you may call different CHM's or is this a standalone CHM?

Comment: We have a core chm help and we have several non-core helps. All chms reside in the same directory. The non-core helps are merged helps, meaning they can be accessed from within the core chm.

Comment: My thought was to compile your themes in different CHM's and make a application call - but just have seen your answer at Adobe forums: "Thanks Peter. Having different versions of the chm is not an option for us. We're trying to cut down on disk space in our downloads. Duplicating all our chms across all 16 languages will cause a spike in an undesired direction."

Comment: Thanks for looking into it. But yeah, unfortunately, that's not an option for us. 

I hope someone has some ideas, I've spent over two full days trying to figure this thing out with no success. It may be that we'll have to change our help output to a local (non-compiled) web based help. (Something I'd like to do anyway.) But at the moment we're stuck with chms as our help format.

Comment: What did you eventually had to do? Did you ship two help files?

Comment: @eri0o, I was never able to get it to work in the CHM format. We ended up just supplying a single-themed CHM file. Later, we switched Help formats; so now our users have an HTML5 browser-based help. This has better potential for supporting theme changes.

Answer (score 0):

> My answer maybe not about this question, but can deal with your needs.

##### Just use the `zeal` not the chm doc.

- change to dark mode for <kbd>Alt+E</kbd>Edit→<kbd>N</kbd>Preference→Content→Appearance (requires restart):<kbd>Alt+D</kbd>Dark.

If your system is set to dark, then you don't need to do anything, it will automatically go dark. Hope you like it.

> but you only want to use the chm doc, there's the suggestions.

1. Only want to read to use: xchm
2. Carry it with you on a USB flash drive：Kchmviewer
3. Manage：Calibre Okular
4. Config and extense：MyBase
5. Export in CLI to another file form：pandoc

```bash
pandoc input.chm -o output.<filetype> # [html|pdf|equb|markdown]
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).